# Compare datatables where columns dont have same Name Precision or Scale

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

Using C#, I am trying to compare 2 data tables who do not have the same column naming / column precision / column scale. They are basically from two different source systems; however they have a column to column mapping and the data is expected to match. Further when comparing, a tolerance of up to  `0.0001` (difference) is allowed in case of numeric fields.

My understanding is LINQ can't be used as they don't match structurally. Is there a better way of doing this other than by looping through each cell resulting into a horrible complexity of O(n^2). The tables are not huge, so I may get away with it but just wondering if there is a better approach.

Further, even if I loop through, statement like

```
valueInCellOfFirstTable.Equals(valueInCellOfSecondTable)
```

Apparently won't work where I want to be agnostic of the data type as well as use tolerance of `0.0001` if it was a numeric field.

Any ideas how to implement this in an effective way?

Comment: If your tables truly are small then pulling both tables down and doing the mapping in memory may be your best bet.  I am getting thrown off by the need to be 'agnostic of the data type'.  You have different numeric data types or you want one algorithm for all possible data types?  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Columns have different data types and there are several such table pairs to compare with one algorithm. Using `.Equals()` is quite nice that I dont worry about the datatypes; However if I have to use a tolerance in checking equality then I would probably end up using a long if else statement on the data types like below and that is very ugly to me  `
 if (val_Tbl1.GetType() == typeof(string))
 {
  result = val_Tbl1.Equals(val_Tbl2);
 }
 else if (val_Tbl1.GetType() == typeof(int))
 {
  result = ((Convert.ToInt32(val_Tbl2) - Convert.ToInt32(val_Tbl1) > 0.0001));
 }
 ....
`

Comment: can you post the models of those 2 tables?